# script file : command stopped

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I made simple script. file name is **sutest**.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Downloads/redis-4.0.1/src
./redis-server

echo "uid is ${UID}"
echo "user is ${USER}"
echo "username is ${USERNAME}"
```

I runed script.`$ . sutest`
But, script code is stopped at `./redis-server`.
So I can't see echo messages.

[image]

I want to make this kind of script files. How can I do that??

I would be appreciate your help.

---

Let's say more general case.
`myscript1` file executes process like redis-server above.
another `myscript2` file executes process like redis-server above.
another `myscript3` file executes process like redis-server above.

How can I run three script files simultaneously??
I want to do job in ssh connection.
To make the matter worse, If I can't use `screen` or `tmux`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a '&' char at the end of the row

```
./redis-server &
```

this char permits to run in backgroud the job, and the script continues.

Comment: thanks for your answer. please read my edit. for more general case.

Comment: Adding a '&' is also applicable? possible?

Comment: in your example you can do ./myscript1 &; ./myscript2 &; ./myscript3 &; and they run together

Comment: thank you for your kind answer. I'll choose your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the echos first:

```
cd ~/Downloads/redis-4.0.1/src

echo "uid is ${UID}"
echo "user is ${USER}"
echo "username is ${USERNAME}"

exec ./redis-server
```

The use of `exec` is a small trick (which you can omit if you prefer): it replaces the shell script with `redis-server`, so the shell script is no longer running at all.  Without `exec`, you end up with the shell script waiting around for `redis-server` to finish, which is unnecessary if the script will do nothing further.

If you don't like that for some reason, you can keep the original order:

```
cd ~/Downloads/redis-4.0.1/src
./redis-server & # run in background

echo "uid is ${UID}"
echo "user is ${USER}"
echo "username is ${USERNAME}"

wait # optional
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. please read my edit. for more general case.

Comment: Adding a '&' is also applicable? possible?

Comment: @newbie16: You can run `thing1 & thing2 & thing3 &; wait`.